# SEO way to create a big website with small aggregate ones

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, aggregators

Let's say I have this website `recipes.com` that has a service that allows to register a lot of recipes. Each recipe belongs to one or more categories. Now I would like to create specialized websites.

```
recipes.com/vegetarian
recipes.com/dukan
recipes.com/paleo
```

Each small website will be a RSS aggregator website with a custom menu different from the site `recipe.com`. How do I optimize it for SEO? Here are my ideas:

1. Display iframe in RSS aggregator sites.
2. Not indexing recipes in `recipes.com`
3. Let content be duplicated
4. May be there is a balance so I can say to Google to ignore content and not consider it duplicated ? Thus for aggregator sites, only the title and introduction of each recipe would be indexed.
5. Just put small excerpt on aggregator sites, and then open window on a new tab that opens the main site with another menu ?

My goal is a great user-experience and also websites that will be optimized for search engines.

Edit:
In response to your comments, sorry for being unclear. I mean :
www.recipes.com will be one wordpress website
www.recipes.com/vegetarian will be a RSS aggregator wordpress website that will show some posts of www.recipes.com. It will have a unique menu.
It will be the same for www.recipes.com/dukan
It will be the same for www.recipes.com/paleo
I was wondering what is the best solution to lower the bad effects of duplicated content.

Comment: You say "website" but then you give an example with directories within the same website.   Which is it?

Comment: I think @StephenOstermiller is right and your question is unclear. However, it is considered bad user-experience and bad SEO to have different menu's on the same domain. If this is what you mean, I suggest you try and redesign your menu. The rule of thumb is to keep the menu as simple as possible. Take a look at this post that explains the ["traveling magnifying glass"-menu](http://searchengineland.com/6-ideas-ecommerce-seo-184995) structure amazon.com uses.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my message and hope it is more clear. I couldn't add return line on the new text.
I thought it was a good idea to have a different website on the same domain in order to boost alexa index.
So it would be better for me to put all of my wordress aggregator rss website on a unique domain name if they requiere a different menu ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate content is almost never a problem within a single domain name.  If all your "websites" are on the `recipes.com` domain name, then Google will not penalize you for duplicate content.

At worst, Google will recognize that two pages are duplicate and choose only one of them to show in the search results.  See: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)